# How to load a notebook without the outputs?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I mistakenly printed to much to the output during a single cell's execution and now the browser tab completely freezes every time that notebook is opened. I tried restarting ipython and it didn't help (I am guessing that each time it is loaded, also all the chunk of text is loaded with it).

Is there a way to load a notebook with outputs suspended or clear?

Answer (score 2):

One hack if you're desperate: open the .ipynb file, which is a text file.  Scroll down to the lengthy cell output and delete it.  Of course, you need to be careful that the result is still a valid .ipynb file.

Comment: not possible in my case its more than 2 lack long texts!

Answer (score 2):

[nbstripout](https://pypi.org/project/nbstripout/) is a simple tool that removes all output from a notebook (without needing to open the notebook in your browser).

Answer (score 0):

your code will be saved in the form of JSON. open it with json viewer and carefully delete the unwanted output cell and save it back.